# The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>' after updating the version of the SDK

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this error, after updating the version of the SDK (to 31 from 29), I can not fix it, I will be grateful for your help. Here is part of the code.
"_userDetails.add(UserDetails.fromJson(user));"

```html
    final responseJson = json.decode(responseBody);
    print(url);
    setState(() {
      for (Map user in responseJson) {
        _userDetails.add(UserDetails.fromJson(user));
      }
    });
```

My class

```html
class UserDetails {

  final String  name, seal_number,sealed,date,userSL;



  UserDetails({required this.name,required this.sealed,required this.seal_number,required this.date,required this.userSL});

  factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new UserDetails(
      sealed: json['sealed'],
      name: json['name'],
      seal_number: json['seal_number'],
      date: json['date'],
      userSL: json['user'],

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the user from `Map` to `Map<String,dynamic>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
_userDetails = responseJson.map((user)=>UserDetails.fromJson(user)).toList();
```